# Python- How to separate input entries separated by delimiters and use them separately later in the code i

Tags: python, scripting-language

I receive an input like this

x= (a:b)

I need to separate a and b and use them individually in the code

a = abc1*xyz1

b = abc2*xyz2

How can I separate two or more entities which are delimited by ":" and use them separately later in the code?

Comment: Have you tried `string.split(':')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is processed as a string:

```
a = inputstring.split('(')[1].split(':')[0]
b = inputstrint.split(':')[1].split(')')[0]
```

This will split the values out of the strings based on the provided delimiters.

Comment: Input is not a string, how can I convert it to a string to use string.split?

Comment: You can convert it to a string with the following line:
    inputstring = str(input)